# How to use get part in url with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

The situation is the Oauth server will redirect to my site with this url:

```
$location.absUrl():http://abcdefg.com/?code=0415fca7f0b126554c768d8fafcba1eL&state=STATE#/wechat
```

However, the result of the `$location.search().code` is undefined

So, I want a correct way to get the code part of the URL.

Comment: what is the result of $location.search()? (to see if code is trying to access an empty object, if it has `state`, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking taking $location string, finding the '=' index with `indexOf`, and splicing the code from `index+1` (to skip the '=') to `indexOf('&')`. It's a little dirty, but could get you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $location.search().code get the value from query string.

Comment: However, the result of the $location.search().code is undefined

Comment: See my post, the result is undefined,Only this way  $location.search().code can get the value: http://abcdf.com/#/wechat?code=0318bfc4691a6eb25afedb078a2d22fo&state=